# jQuery loop through form elements and select specific id

Tags: jquery

Currently I'm looping through my form elements and validating it by checking
against if a user has input anything. Except I need to use a different 
validation for a specific field. Specifically I need to validate if a valid
phone number.  Here is my code. I'm looping through all input elements but 
need to pick out the element that has an id phoneNumber and see if it is a 
valid phone number.  It's simply not hitting the conditional that sees if the 
attribute is a phone number. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$("#phoneForm :input").each(function(){

    var placeholderText = $(this).attr("placeholder");                          

    if($(this).val().length == 0){             
        alert(placeholderText.replace('*','') + ' field is required');
        $(this).focus();
        valid = false;
        return false;
    }       

    if($(this).attr("id['phoneNumber']")){
    alert(placeholderText + " check phone number");
    }

});
```

Comment: `id['phoneNumber']` isn't a valid attribute name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll need to change your conditional statement to look something like this :

```
if($(this).attr("id") == 'phoneNumber'){
  alert(placeholderText + " check phone number");
}
```

The selector `id[phoneNumber]` is simply not valid. I think you are confusing the syntax with another selector... If you wanted to match only the elements that have `phoneNumber` in their ID, you would use something like this:

```
$("element[id='phoneNumber']")
```

Although that example might be a little strange as there is a specific selector to match the id of an element. But.. as we all know - there is more than one way to skin a unicorn :)

---

Once final note: You have used `$(this).attr("id")` to extract the `id` of a given element when in fact you could simply use native JavaScript to extract that property like this :

```
this.id
```

So to put that all together would result in something like this:

```
if(this.id == 'phoneNumber'){
  alert(placeholderText + " check phone number");
}
```

This will definitely improve the the performance of the code even if you don't really feel it at this stage. You will start to notice the improvements once you start working with some more complex and intensive JS applications.
(Thanks to [David Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/david-thomas) for pointing that out to me and to [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) for convincing me to edit my answer :P)

Comment: Preferably: `this.id == 'phoneNumber'`.

Comment: @dav - why? Are you saying that from some performance or optimization standpoint? If so, I think it might be a little bit overkill... In simple cases (as I assume this one is) there really will not be *that* much difference...

Comment: `$(this).attr("id")` is the creation of an object and two function calls and a property reference vs. `this.id` which is one property reference.  It's very clear which is simpler and faster.  jQuery should ONLY be used when it's faster to code or execute than not using it.  Just because you have jQuery doesn't mean one should forget the simplest ways that plain javascript can be used.

Comment: I'm basically going to point to jfriend00's response/explanation, and say "*that.*" =)

Comment: @dav Hehe - yea - I do 100% agree with you on that - however I tend to tailor my answers here to best suit the needs of the OP, sure there are a load of things that could be done to improve on the logic and even the selectors used but for this simple case I felt it would be better to simply demonstrate the correct way to do what **they** want as opposed to jumping into an optimization lecture about when and where to use vanilla JS over jQuery... I'll repeat myself and say that you both are totally correct...

Comment: @Lix thanks for replying your suggestion works but I'm getting two alerts. One 
that hits the initial conditional and another that now hits the phone number 
conditional. How do I remove it hitting the initial conditional and just hit
the one targeted at the phone number.

Comment: You might want to consider placing all the invalid field errors into an array and then alerting the contents of that array at the end of your validation instead of immediately as you detect a problem...

Comment: @Lix - you received a comment on how to simplify and improve your code.  Why not just use the edit button to do so?  Good answers on SO incorporate improvements based on comments.  Instead you argue about why you don't want to change it.  Makes no sense to me.   No need to be defensive - just improve your code.

Comment: @Lix it would be helpful if you could edit your code. Newbie here that would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @del - that's kind of a different question.. I'm not sure it would be correct of me to add that to my existing answer.. Perhaps you'll be able to find a similar question with an already existing answer on the site.. Failing that, I'd recommend simply opening a new question.